# Is there a way to change the name of GAS that appears in the browser tab?

Tags: google-apps-script

Normally, when a GAS project is deployed as a web app, the value that appears in the tab of the browser when running the application is the current web app url. Is there a way to customise this value? 
My application is based on html service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setTitle on the HtmlOutput object to change that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply